# Create wordpress function to get post thumbnail url as template tag

Tags: php, wordpress

I need a code implemented within function.php so I can get post thumbnail url as template tag `get_thumbnail_url`.

So far I am using this code within the template files:

```
<?php
$thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'full' );
$thumb_url = $thumb['0'];
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wrap it in a function?

```
function get_post_thumbnail_url() {
    $thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'full' );
    return $thumb ? $thumb[0] : '';
}
```

And then use it within The Loop:

```
$src = get_post_thumbnail_url();
```